# PHP/MySQL Show first X results, hide the rest

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know how to bring in all of a mysql tables' results, only show the first X, (say 10), and then hide the rest using jquery? I just need to know how to show only the first X results in one page, then the rest in a seperate page using href.

My aim is to only show the first 10 results, but provide a link at the bottom of the page allowing the user to show all of the results. Was thinking the hyperlink could just re-execute the query but thought it would be easier to show/hide using jquery.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are searching for Pagination. There are some useful jQuery paginations plugins:

- [jQuery pagination plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination)
- [DataTables Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/)

Or using PHP:

- [Pagination in PHP](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using jquery, you can use MySQL to retrieve only the desired results.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 10
```

That will retreive the first 10 results. Then, to display the next 10 on the next page,

```
SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

and the next page

```
SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

If you are using PHP, you can build your query to show the correct results depending on which page you are on:

```
// $currentPage is set elsewhere in the script, and is zero-based.
$resultsPerPage = 10;

$currentOffset = $resultsInPage * $currentPage;
$query = "SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT $resultsInPage OFFSET $currentOffset";
```

Comment: This is the method i would use too. If you have a large dataset returned from MySQL, you'll find some performance issues with pagination plugins. Only returning the group of records you need is usually the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need pagination look at the some tutorial to do this. there are lot of code examples on this do googling

here are some links

http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/ -

http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm

Answer (score 0):

It might be "easier", but it's a lot less resource efficient to load all the data (and then optionally show it) in the manner you're describing.

I'd really recommend using multiple queries (perhaps via Ajax/lazy loading) rather than using the approach you're discussing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) statement in the Select-statement of your SQL query. In most cases there's no need to send all the data to the client and then let javascript hide the data you don't wanna show.