# Display more from database on click PHP, JQUERY, MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, web

I'm working on a website and am pulling category names from a db table (category_names). I then display them on the website using php on to an html unordered list. I want to limit the number of category_names and then using jquery(or anything else but I prefer jQuery) retrieve more category_names and add a less button to go back.

[image: this is what im trying to achieve]

I hope I made this question easy to understand, and thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of different approaches that work better or worse depending upon your needs.

Approach 1 (simpler, less efficient, scales poorly): execute the full query, and store all of the results on the DOM, just hiding them using jQuery (jQuery expander is a simple plugin you may want to try out, though I have found it limiting in customization).

Approach 2 (more complicated, but more efficient/scalable, also faster): Use MySQL limit, you can actually send a second mysql request on click, however, you would want to make sure this is asynchronous so as to not delay the user's interactions.
http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

This is similar to: [PHP/MySQL Show first X results, hide the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489866/php-mysql-show-first-x-results-hide-the-rest)

Comment: this is a great answer thank you... I think I might try Approach 2... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 12):

Basically use AJAX to pull in more. Start off by loading in a few by using `LIMIT`.

```
<ul id="categories">
<?php
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `category_names` LIMIT 10'); // change limit to suit
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo '<li>'.$row['name'].'</li>'; // or whatever your field is called
    }
?>
</ul>
<span id="loadmore" num_loaded="10">Load More</span>
```

Then use the following jQuery to load more:

```
$('#loadmore').click(function() {
    var loaded = $(this).attr('num_loaded');
    $.ajax({
        url:'load_categories.php',
        type:'get',
        data:{'from':loaded,'to':loaded+10},
        success: function (res) {
            var categories = $.parseJSON(res);
            categories.each(function() {
                $('#categories').append('<ul>'+this+'</ul>');
            });
            $('#loadmore').attr('num_loaded',loaded+10);
        }
    });
});
```

Finally you'll need to create the PHP page that the AJAX calls - **load_categories.php**

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['from'])) exit;
if (!isset($_GET['to'])) exit;

$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$diff = $from-$to;

// connect / select db
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `category_names` LIMIT '.$from-1.','.$to.';');
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($arr,$row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Comment: Hi. Seems like a nice solutions, but I have a question. Will it reload all the data again or data after first 10 records?

Comment: Dude I'm gonna worship you

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do something simpler:

```
 $get = mysqli_queury ($link, "SELECT * FROM db_name WHERE blank='blank' LIMIT 5"
 if (isset($_POST['button']; {
 $get = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM db_name WHERE blank='blank' LIMIT 10"
 }
?>
<form action="showmore.php" method="POSt">
<input type="button" id="button" name="button">
</form>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use a datagrid with pagenation. I think [datatable JQuery pluggin](http://datatables.net/) will work well for you